# Pushing into Nested array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

This is my mongoose Schema

```js
const notesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    college: {type:String},
    year: {type:String},
    sem: {type:String},
    branch:{type:String},
    subjects: [
        {
            subject_id:{type:String},
            name:{type:String},
            codename: {type:String},
            notes: [
                {
                    notes_id:{type:String}, 
                    title: {type:String},
                    material: [
                        {
                            material_id:{type:String},
                            heading:{type:String},
                            link: {type:String}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

I want to insert a object into 'material' array which is inside notes array and notes is inside subjects array.

I tried many syntax, but none of them worked for me. Recently I tried this.

```js
 try {
     notes.updateOne({
        $and:[ {_id: '62a61949dc0f920ae99fc687'}, {'subjects.notes.notes_id':'221fad-f35c-ee2a-65b3-8531dbfcf732'}] 
    }, 
        {$push:{'subjects.0.notes.$.material': 
        [{ material_id: "hfklahfhoabfoab", heading: "Prime", link: "wwo.prime.com" }] 
    }}
```

This is full function code:-

```js
router.get('/populate',async (req,res)=>{
    // const {data} = req.body
    // const link = "www.wiki.com"
   try {
     notes.updateOne({
        _id: '62a61949dc0f920ae99fc687',
        'subjects.notes.notes_id': '221fad-f35c-ee2a-65b3-8531dbfcf732',
      }, 
        {$push:{'subjects.0.notes.$.material': 
        [{ material_id: "hfklahfhoabfoab", heading: "Prime", link: "wwo.prime.com" }] 
    }}
        
    )
    console.log("posted") 
    const alreadyexist = await notes.find({$and:[{"year":'3'},{"sem":'2'}]})
    res.send(alreadyexist)
   // console.log(updata) 
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   }
} )
```

This is my current Database status.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIOZe.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean 'none worked?' Did they update but clear everything else? My guess (it's been a while) is that you need to set the `merge` property to make sure that the *old* data merges with the new changes. That's just off the top of my head but we'd need more info to help you.

Comment: These syntax does not affected my database. Nothing got reflected in the database .No value changed in the DB. I want to push objects into my database at a particular index in a particular array. Here I want to push into 'material'. I am looking for a proper solution/syntax to perform this.